# Laravel 5 - Method Not Allowed on POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to save a backbone model using model.save().

The url I'm trying to send a POST method to is: `http://localhost/user`
My route is: `Route::POST('/user/{user}', 'Dashboard\Dashboard@newUser');`

But I get a `Method Not Allowed Exception`

Can you see what's wrong in my code?

Comment: `Route::POST('/user', 'Dashboard\Dashboard@newUser');` unless your passing an ID id or something to new user. Your current route expects /user/(?)

Comment: I'm expecting to get a user json object

Comment: Then why are you going to a `newUser` method surely thats for creating and for getting you'd have a `getUser` also your URL does not include an ID or anything.

Comment: `newUser` just echoing the arguments for now, but I don't event get there.

Comment: Well to hit that route regardless you'll need to do a POST request too `http://localhost/user/1`

Comment: Yeah, sure. But how can I pass a json object and fetch it in the route?

Comment: You put it in the body of the post, not in the url. You will find the data in `$request->input()`

Answer (score 2):

And you should look at case sensitivity when you look at the documentation.

```
Route::post('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Its lowercase. Sometimes that can cause problems.

The next thing is that "named routes" looks like the following:

```
Route::get('user/profile', [
    'as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
]);
```

I haven't tried that in your way but in that way its working.

And the last thing is that you should pass an ID to your route otherwise the route is not correct. in your case `/user/1` for example.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing